# Display waiting screen when user selects UITable row

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When the user selects a row in my table, I need to load a bunch of data with CoreData.  This takes several seconds (at least when running on the simulator - haven't tested on a device yet, but I imagine it will still be pretty long).  I want to display a loading popover screen (I'm developing for iPad) when the user selects a row, then have it disappear once the data is loaded.

When working with UIButtons, I've always done this by triggering both a TouchDown and TouchUp method.  I put the code to display the popover on the TouchDown, then do all my actual work (so in this case loading from CoreData) in the TouchUp.  Then at the end of TouchUp, I close the popover.

Is there a way to split up touches in a table view the same way as ones on a button?

Comment: Several seconds!? Can you optimize your data any? That seems like far too long to load.

Comment: It's a lot of data.  I don't use all of it right away, so I suppose I could try to break it up a little so it takes less time per access, but getting it all at once just felt like the more organized way to do it.  And it's nice knowing that once I do this load, I have everything I'm going to need, so I don't have to worry about situations where I might have loaded the data needed for a certain operation under some circumstances but not others.  In all, I think it's better this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I was typing up the question I came across something in the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and it looks like that is there to address this very issue.  I didn't see any other topics on this on SO, so I figured I'd make use of this "Answer own question - Q&A" feature on here, so maybe people looking for this in the future will find it a little easier.

---

Huge FYI block:

I should note that `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` is actually supposed to return an `NSIndexPath`, unlike `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (which returns `void`).  However, I originally had

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //stuff
}
```

Note the `void` return type.  Xcode (Version 4.5) allowed this without any errors or warnings (and even had it for me in the autocomplete list).  When I ran the code this way, I always hit an invisible breakpoint in `libobjc.A.dylib'objc_autorelease:` (maybe becaues I have the "All Exceptions" breakpoint enabled?).  I couldn't get past this breakpoint, I never got any debug information in the debugger output console, and the app never terminated.  I happened to look at the Apple Doc again and notice that it was supposed to return an NSIndexPath (specifically, the index path the code should interpret as being the one that was selected), but if I didn't happen to see it there, I never would have known what the problem was.

---